# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError while testing Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am learning Spring and i created the following interfaces and classes all under the same package

```
public interface CompactDisc {
    public void play();
}
```

-

```
@Component
public class StgPeppers implements CompactDisc{
    private String title = "Stg. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";
    @Override
    public void play(){
        System.out.println("Playing "+title+" by "+artist);
    }
}
```

-

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

That are tested using

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(cd);
    }

}
```

I am following these examples from a book, it asks to test that it's working but not how to do that so i created under the same package a main class that just does that

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new CDPlayerTest().cdShouldNotBeNull();
    }

}
```

In the console i have

```
Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:55)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:256)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:248)
at automaticWiring.CDPlayerTest.cdShouldNotBeNull(CDPlayerTest.java:30)
at automaticWiring.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

All the imports of the classes are correct even if omitted, i am using a Netbeans webapp with Spring Web MVC framework, i also had to add *JUnit 4.12* jar to the library since it wasn't there at the beginning.
Is there something wrong with the Spring code or is my testing method incorrect ?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You never initialized the member `cd`, and also I believe you are not supposed to invoke the test method directly, but let JUnit invoke it.

Comment: How should i initialize it ?

Comment: right click on the test file in your IDE > run

Comment: if i run the "CDPlayerTest" i have "Class "CDPlayerTest" neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web.xml". i added in the main thread the web.xml

Comment: I think the class needs to be injected into your testing class. Your @ContextConfiguration annotation should point to your test class

Comment: You mean changing _@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)_ to _@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerTest.class)_ ? I have the same error if i do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381512/how-do-i-run-junit-from-netbeans

Comment: If i use the create junit test from tools as suggested i have another class that with a test method simply calls the other test method cdShouldNotBeNull() in the CDPlayerTest class. I have the same error "Class "CDPlayerTest" neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that the test-class loads the entire application context whene before executing the tests.

Comment: With Spring Framework 4.0.1 and junit 4.12 libraries i can't import _SpringBootTest_ nor _SpringRunner_