# Java: Determine if a 2D array has discontiguous values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a question. I have a 2D array in Java, and I want to check the array if the array has discontiguous value or not.

Example:

```
True:
1 2 3 3
1 4 4 5
2 6 6 5
7 7 8 8
```

The array above should return true since the number 2 appears in 2 discontiguous areas (row 1 col 2 and row 3 col 1).

```
False:
1 2 3 3
1 4 4 5
6 7 7 5
8 8 9 9
```

The array above should return false since there are no values that appear in 2 or more discontiguous areas.

Comment: I haven't found a way since it's a 2D array, and I can't sort the array as I want to check the unsorted 2D array for discontiguous values.

Comment: is a number that is contiguous adjacently is accepted?

Comment: can values be contiguous diagonally?

Comment: Yes, it's accepted as long as the numbers are contiguous horizontally or vertically. Values can't be contiguous diagonally.

Comment: Let me test the solutions below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, we need to group each array values' locations. Once we know all positions, we need to find out whether these are all adjacent (for each pos1, there is pos2 with distance(pos1, pos2) < 2).

```
public class ContiguousArray {

    public static <E> boolean isContiguous(E[][] array) {
        Map<E, Collection<Integer[]>> groupedPositions = groupLocations(array);

        return groupedPositions.values().stream().allMatch(ContiguousArray::allContiguous);
    }

    private static <E> Map<E, Collection<Integer[]>> groupLocations(E[][] array) {
        Map<E, Collection<Integer[]>> locations = new HashMap<>();

        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {

                Collection<Integer[]> knownIndices;
                Integer[] currentPosition = new Integer[] { x, y };
                E currentElement = array[x][y];

                if(locations.containsKey(currentElement)) {
                    knownIndices = locations.get(currentElement);
                } else {
                    knownIndices = new HashSet<>();

                    locations.put(currentElement, knownIndices);
                }
                knownIndices.add(currentPosition);
            }
        }
        return locations;
    }

    /**
     * @return true, if all of the provided indices have an adjacent index in
     *         the same collection. Also true, if the collection's size < 2.
     *         False, otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean allContiguous(Collection<Integer[]> indices) {
        return indices.stream().allMatch(thisIndex -> hasAdjacent(indices, thisIndex) || indices.size() < 2);
    }

    private static boolean hasAdjacent(Collection<Integer[]> indices, Integer[] thisIndex) {
        return indices.stream().anyMatch(thatIndex -> isAdjacent(thisIndex, thatIndex));
    }

    private static boolean isAdjacent(Integer[] thisIndex, Integer[] thatIndex) {
        return thatIndex != thisIndex && calculateDistance(thisIndex, thatIndex) < 2;
    }

    private static int calculateDistance(Integer[] indexA, Integer[] indexB) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < indexA.length; i++) {
            sum += Math.abs(indexA[i] - indexB[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Along with a JUnit test:

```
public class ContiguousArrayTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertFalse(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] { 
            { 1, 2, 3, 3 }, 
            { 1, 4, 4, 5 }, 
            { 2, 6, 6, 5 }, 
            { 7, 7, 8, 8 } 
        }));

        assertFalse(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Character[][] { 
            { 'a', 'b' }, 
            { 'b', 'a' }, 
        }));

        assertTrue(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Character[][] { 
            { 'a', 'a', 'a' }, 
            { 'b', 'a' }, 
            { 'b' }, 
        }));

        assertTrue(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] { 
            { 1, 2, 3, 3 }, 
            { 1, 4, 4, 5 }, 
            { 6, 7, 7, 5 }, 
            { 8, 8, 9, 9 } 
        }));

        assertTrue(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] { 
            { 1, 2, 3, 3 }, 
            { 1, 1, 4, 5 }, 
            { 6, 1, 7, 5 }, 
            { 8, 8, 9, 9 } 
        }));

        assertTrue(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] { 
            { 1, 2 }, 
            { 2, 2 }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't really need JUnit to test this class... just write a `public static void main[] { System.out.println(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] {...}));  }`. What's your problem with JUnit anyway? Don't you use an IDE?

Comment: I'm using netbeans

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381512/how-do-i-run-junit-from-netbeans) help? What's the error?

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks very much!I can run it after changing the test format to the `public static void main[] { System.out.println(ContiguousArray.isContiguous(new Integer[][] {...})); }` format

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below. The comments explain what is happening.
It contains three classes: `ArraysMain`, `Index` and `IndexList` which extends an `ArrayList`.

**UPDATED**

Basically, get all the distinct values and store them in a map. For each value (if it appears more than once) will have multiple indexes (the position of the value in the array).

Iterate through the array adding the indexes for each value one by one. If you encounter an index whose rowIndex does not match the rowIndex of all other indexes and same for columnIndex for the current value, then that value is discontigous.

```
public class ArraysMain {

private static final int[][] values = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4, 5}, {2, 6, 6, 5}, {7, 7, 8, 8}};
// private static final int[][] values = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 7, 5}, {8, 8, 9, 9}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Has Discontigous: " + hasDiscontigous());
}

public static boolean hasDiscontigous() {
    // Initialize a map to hold the indexes for each int found
    // For example the value 3 will be mapped to the indexes as shown below
    // (3) -> [0,2], [0,3]
    // (4) -> [1,1], [1,2]
    Map<Integer, IndexList<Index>> map = new HashMap<>();

    // Iterate through the int array and add the indexes per the value
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        // Get the i-th row
        int[] row = values[i];

        // Iterate through the current row values and add them to the map with the corresponding indexes
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            // If the map does not contain the j-th value then that value has not been added yet so 
            // Initialize the List
            if (!map.containsKey(row[j])) {
                // Initialize the list
                map.put(row[j], new IndexList<>());
            }

            // Get the value's indexes list and add this value's index
            // If the value is added to the list, 'true' is returned
            boolean add = map.get(row[j]).add(new Index(i, j));

            if (!add) {
                // If false means a discontiguous value has been found
                System.out.println("Value: " + values[i][j] + " is discontigous");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * This will hold the indexes i.e rowIndex and columnIndex
 */
public static class Index {

    private int rowIndex;
    private int columnIndex;

    public Index(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public int getRowIndex() {
        return rowIndex;
    }

    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }

    public int getColumnIndex() {
        return columnIndex;
    }

    public void setColumnIndex(int columnIndex) {
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

}

/**
 * Extend the {@code ArrayList} object and override the add() method
 * @param <T> 
 */
public static class IndexList<T> extends ArrayList<Index> {

    /**
     * This method determines if a discontigous value has been found. If a value is not discontigous it's indexes are added to the list, 
     * if not, this method returns false
     * @param e
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean add(Index e) {
        // Before adding an index object ensure the row or column do not match

        for (Index thi : this) {
            // Check if the rows match
            if (e.rowIndex != thi.rowIndex && e.columnIndex != thi.columnIndex) {
                // If the rowIndex and columnIndex do not match then don't add the value
                return false;
            }

        }

        return super.add(e); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It produces wrong result for `private static final int[][] values = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2} };`.

Comment: @Kihats Thank you for answering, but SME_Dev found that your solution has a mistake.

Comment: @michaeladrian39 What is the expected result for SME_Dev's example, `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solutoin. Bit simpler to understand, though needs optimization.

UPDATE: This simply check if each value is discontiguous or not and if yes, then one or more than one.

```
public class CheckIfDiscontiguous {
public static void main(String args []){
    CheckIfDiscontiguous so = new CheckIfDiscontiguous();
    int[][] input = {{1,2,3,3}, {1,4,4,5}, {2,7,7,5}, {8,8,9,9}};
    System.out.println(so.discontiguousValueCheck(input));
}
public boolean discontiguousValueCheck(int[][] input){
    int m=4;
    int n=4;
    int flag = 0;
    int count = 1;
    int discontiguousCount = 1;
    int[] discontiguousSuspects = new int[16]; 
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){

            //check for 1st row starts
            //check for (0,0)
            if(i==0 && j==0){    
                if(!(input[0][0]==input[0][1] || input[0][0]==input[1][0])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[0][0];
                }
            }
            //check for (0,1)
            if(i==0 && j==1){
                if(!(input[0][1]==input[0][0] || input[0][1]==input[0][2] || input[0][1]==input[1][1])){
                    //System.out.println("goes");
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[0][1];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[0][1]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (0,2)
            if(i==0 && j==2){
                if(!(input[0][2]==input[0][1] || input[0][2]==input[0][3] || input[0][2]==input[1][2])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[0][2];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[0][2]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (0,3)
            if(i==0 && j==3){
                if(!(input[0][3]==input[0][2] || input[0][3]==input[1][3])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[0][3];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[0][3]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for 1st row ends

            //check for 2nd row elements start
            //check for (1,0)
            if(i==1 && j==0){    
                if(!(input[1][0]==input[0][0] || input[1][0]==input[2][0] || input[1][0]==input[1][1])) {
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[1][0];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[1][0]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (1,1)
            if(i==1 && j==1){
                if(!(input[1][1]==input[1][0] || input[1][1]==input[0][1] || input[1][1]==input[1][2] || input[1][1]==input[2][1])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[1][1];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[1][1]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (1,2)
            if(i==1 && j==2){
                if(!(input[1][2]==input[1][1] || input[1][2]==input[0][2] || input[1][2]==input[1][3] || input[1][2]==input[2][2])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[1][2];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[1][2]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (1,3)
            if(i==1 && j==3){
                if(!(input[1][3]==input[1][2] || input[1][3]==input[0][3] || input[1][3]==input[2][3])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[1][3];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[1][3]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //check for 2nd row elements end


            //check for 3rd row elements start
            //check for (2,0)
            if(i==2 && j==0){    
                if(!(input[2][0]==input[1][0] || input[2][0]==input[3][0] || input[2][0]==input[2][1])) {
                    count++;
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[2][0];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[2][0]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                                discontiguousCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (2,1)
            if(i==2 && j==1){
                if(!(input[2][1]==input[2][0] || input[2][1]==input[1][1] || input[2][1]==input[2][2] || input[2][1]==input[3][1])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[2][1];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[2][1]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (2,2)
            if(i==2 && j==2){
                if(!(input[2][2]==input[2][1] || input[2][2]==input[1][2] || input[2][2]==input[2][3] || input[2][2]==input[3][2])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[2][2];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[2][2]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (2,3)
            if(i==2 && j==3){
                if(!(input[2][3]==input[2][2] || input[2][3]==input[1][3] || input[2][3]==input[3][3])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[1][3];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[2][3]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //check for 3rd row elements end

            //check for 4th row starts
            //check for (3,0)
            if(i==3 && j==0){    
                if(!(input[3][0]==input[3][1] || input[3][0]==input[2][0])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[3][0];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[2][3]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (3,1)
            if(i==3 && j==1){
                if(!(input[3][1]==input[3][0] || input[0][1]==input[3][2] || input[3][1]==input[2][1])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[3][1];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[3][1]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (3,2)
            if(i==3 && j==2){
                if(!(input[3][2]==input[3][1] || input[3][2]==input[3][3] || input[3][2]==input[2][2])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[3][2];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[3][2]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for (3,3)
            if(i==0 && j==3){
                if(!(input[3][3]==input[3][2] || input[3][3]==input[2][3])){
                    discontiguousSuspects[index] = input[3][3];
                    index++;
                    if(discontiguousSuspects.length>=2){
                        for(int k = 0; k<discontiguousSuspects.length; k++){
                            if(discontiguousSuspects[k]==input[3][3]){
                                if(discontiguousCount==2){
                                return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check for 3rd row ends

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: It fails for `int[][] input = { { 1,` **2** `, 3, 3 }, { 1, 1, 4, 5 }, {` **2, 2** `, 7, 5 }, { 8, 2, 9, 9 } };`

Comment: @Rishav Mishra, Thank you for answering... But SME_Dev found that your solution has a mistake.

Comment: @SME_Dev In the scenarios pointed out by you, gives false for me. Is it giving the same for you? This i consider as expected output for such input because 2 have another 2 in adjacent to it horizontally in third row. So, 2 is only discontigious in the first row i.e. only one time. As quoted by michaeladrian "The array above should return false since there are no values that appear in 2 or more discontiguous areas." in the question, it should return false. I hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: @michaelarian29 Can you please check my comment? I hope that my understanding with terms of requirement is correct. Good that you got your answer. :-)

Comment: @RishavMishra I think you are mixing up the boolean logic, because expressions in the OP are logically inverted several times. In the mentioned example, your code must return `true`, because the rule _no values that appear in 2+ areas := False_ does not apply here. Or in other words: _values that appear in 2+ areas := True_

Comment: @SME_Dev OK. I will try and edit my answer. Is this question an standard question? so, that i can better understand the requirement. Also, thanks for pointing out the mistake.